# Diagnose slow script executions on specific server

Tags: mysql, windows-server, mysql-8.0

I work with an unmanaged server in a remote datacenter to host web based applications. When we run the SQL scripts to create and populate an application database the whole process is painfully slow. A set of scripts that in my underpowered local PC runs in **5 seconds**, on the remote server can take up to **20 minutes**.

When I check the running processes I can see it isn't stuck in any specific statement, it's simply that each one takes several seconds, specially `ALTER TABLE` statements:

```
ALTER TABLE foo_bar
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_foo_bar_foo_id
FOREIGN KEY (foo_id)
REFERENCES foo (id)
```

It's a brand new app, so most tables are empty or have at most a few hundred rows. But slowness already happens much before the `INSERT INTO` statements. All tables are InnoDB.

I run the scripts through command-line PHP if that matters. There's no antivirus I'm aware of. MySQL/8.0 was installed with Windows MySQL Installer and runs as service with this configuration:

```
[client]
port=3306
[mysql]
no-beep
[mysqld]
port=3306
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="FOO.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="FOO-slow.log"
long_query_time=10
log-error="FOO.err"
server-id=1
lower_case_table_names=1
secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads"
max_connections=151
table_open_cache=2000
tmp_table_size=16M
thread_cache_size=10
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
key_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=0
read_rnd_buffer_size=0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8M
innodb_log_file_size=48M
innodb_thread_concurrency=17
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=256K
max_allowed_packet=4M
max_connect_errors=100
open_files_limit=4161
sort_buffer_size=256K
table_definition_cache=1400
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
loose_mysqlx_port=33060
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
log-bin = OFF
skip-bin-log
```

Where can I start looking at this? What diagnostics can I try?

Comment: From 8.0, what is result of SELECT @@version;? Additional information request. RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? Post on pastebin.com and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; E) complete MySQLTuner report - A Windows version is available at - github.com/pmachapman/mysqltuner F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please consider posting the deta requested on Jul 18 at 22:33 so someone can assist with your 'slow script executions' on 8.0.nn.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I'll keep it in mind but it can take a while; unfortunately I don't own neither the server nor my time and the issue only affects new application set ups, which happen once in a blue moon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version is each server using?

`ALTER TABLE` has become significantly slower in 8.0.  It probably has to do with the ability to rollback DDLs.

It has never been wise to depend on a lot of DDLs, but this makes it worse.

If this `ALTER` was being done to a brand new table, it probably would have been better to include the `CONSTRAINT` as part of the table definition.  Of course, if the `ALTER` was generated by mysqldump`, this is not practical.  Furthermore, FKs are very picky about order, so you may be stuck.

Comment: Interesting... Fast server is 5.x, slow one is 8.0.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - This new feature is very costly.

Answer (score 0):

Filenames in your configuration should NOT be surrounded with quotes.
Never seen anyone run with read_buffer_size and read_rnd_buffer_size=0.
Disable these two lines by leading the line with # and a space character to allow defaults to work for you.